# Shortcut to select a character

Tags: dota-2

Is there a keyboard shortcut to quickly select a character.

It used to be CTRL+ENTER but I think they changed it recently in a patch.

Example, to select pudge in the past you could type 'P', 'U', 'D' then CTRL+ENTER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> now.

Unnecessary example to bypass minimum character limit, type "invok" then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.